# WatiN pressTab doesn't press tab

Tags: c#, .net, cucumber, watin

Has anyone found a means to press tab with watiN in Internet explorer?

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean you want to press the tab key itself, or just click on an HTML element that looks like a tab? For the latter use the Click method against the appropriate element (Div, Span etc). Otherwise you could try SendKeys instead of PressTab. e.g.:

```
IE ie = new IE("http://www.google.com");
ie.AutoClose = false;
ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).Click();
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
```

The above example will set the focus the text field then tab off, putting focus on the search button.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem, we resolve it focusin on the browser and using SendMessage (Win) to the specific hwnd.